# how to sort a structure array in VC 6.0

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, structure, visual-c++-6

here's the question. i've defined a struct:

```
typedef struct {

        long t;
        long M;
        long double coeff;
} Info;
```

and i can only know the number of the structures in the following program, thus i wrote:

Info *p = (Info*) malloc (sizeof(Info) * sum );  (where sum is a long integer)

and now i want to sort the structure array according to 'coeff' in ascending order.

how could i achieve it in VC++6.0?

thanks a lot!

Comment: VC++6 is old, but I think it still has `std::sort`.

Comment: That looks a lot more like C than C++.

Answer (score 2):

you can implement a compare function then call std::sort.

```
bool comparator(const Info& p1, const Info& p2)
{
  return p1.coeff < p2.coeff;
}
```

You can also overload the `<` operator in your struct definition instead of writing a standalone compare function.

then call std::sort

```
std::sort(A, A+sum, comparator);
```

assume that `A` is your struct array.

Answer (score 2):

Use [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) with a suitable comparison functor:

```
bool cmp(const Info& lhs, const Info& rhs)
{
  return lhs.coeff < rhs.coeff;
}
```

then

```
#include <algorithm>

std::sort(p, p + sum, cmp);
```

assuming `p` is a pointer to the first element of an array containing `sum` `Info` objects.

But in C++ you would usually prefer an `std::vector` over a dynamically allocated array:

```
std::vector<Info> v(sum); // contains sum default constructed Infos
```

then

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), cmp);
```

You don't need the `typedef` syntax either:

```
struct Info {
    long t;
    long M;
    long double coeff;
};
```

Comment: thanks a lot! i'm still new to c++, thank you for your introducing vector to me.